# Can I change the name of an NFS export

Tags: linux, centos, nfs

I am exporting my /opt/target directory via NFS but I would like the nfs clients to be able to mount it as /target.  i.e. I would like showmount -e to show /target not /opt/target.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure NFS does not allow for aliases. Symlinking is probably best, and it'll save you from moving the export as a whole to an illogical location (/target).

The original suggestion here was to symlink /opt/target to /target and then export /target. NFS supports this and I don't know of any good reasons not to use symlinks this way.

Comment: I have done this and it works well as long as you remember that symlinks in the exported directory will not be translated. If you've got a relative link to ../../../bar and your NFS mount is a symlink to /foo, then anything looking at /foo/bar will actually try to look in /foo/../../../bar

Comment: I looked far and wide for 'aliasing' but did not find anything for NFS.

I also originally entered an answer which suggested symlinking, however when I did showmount -e it showed the original directory anyway, so symlinking does not appear to work as an 'alias' either.

Comment: If I symlink /opt/target to /target then the export would come out as something like /target/opt/target as it seems to append the actual path and the symlink. Using `mount --bind` as per TNT's answer below solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

What you want is how NFSv4 works. In NFSv4, all the directories exported are from a single pseudo-filesystem where the real directories are mounted with `--bind`. See the [Ubuntu NFSv4 Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Since for me wzzrd's answer didn't work and Kamil Kisiel's answer refers to an external source I'll describe here how it exactly works for the op's use case:

```sh
sudo mkdir /target
sudo mount --bind /opt/target /target
sudo exportfs -arv
```

results in output:

```
exporting 192.168.178.90/24:/target
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the path on the server. I'm not sure if you can export via a symlink, otherwise you'd need to move the path physically on the server. Looking at the man page for exports, you might be able to use the "refer" option.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously a way this can be done, because it's exactly what my QNAP does. Showing the exports from qnap451plus, then the exports from qnap451plus , seen from another system:

```
[admin@qnap451plus graeme]# exportfs -s
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Download  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=bba46d1aa4b68e6ba697d935164e1abf,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/InternalAdmin  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=1e63b3f350ad7a5a452bea848e936c1c,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Multimedia  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=33172f1e47c9173a0e9d13ed82b65885,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Public  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=37b143ba0ca575d37a356ab03a7a28db,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Recordings  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=ece917106e8f2512887e54c1e919cc78,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/USBUploads  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=058b9250c295797042f6831f68b57bb9,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Web  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=e0cd2aff70d6e8230b19741d75feef97,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/git  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=87460a2c467625ffe65bebb837fbf6cc,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/homes  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=405caac1b0396839a07a6afec822624a,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/svn  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,fsid=a7cce6eafb9344f595f0c7c53699c34f,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

but seen as:

```
~$ showmount -e qnap451plus
Export list for qnap451plus:
/svn           *
/homes         *
/git           *
/Web           *
/USBUploads    *
/Recordings    *
/Public        *
/Multimedia    *
/InternalAdmin *
/Download      *
```

Now I've tried manually exporting filesystems from qnap451plus using exportfs(1) , but nothing definitive . The test exports either did not appear or causes the exports to "crash" on qnap451plus.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/566540)

Comment: There seems to be a view that the request from the OP is not possible. I too, want to do this. The example (QNAP) shows it possible. I simply can;t work out how QNAP have done it.